# Sending Message to Discord Channel without message from user

Tags: c#, twitch, discord, discord.net

Basically what I am looking for is some way to find a channel name such as announcements and send a message to it. I know how to send a message whenever a user sends a message through discord or if an event happens in discord

```
e.Server.FindChannels("Channel Name").FirstorDefault;
await channel.sendmessage(string.Format("Message"))
```

but I am looking to send a message when an event happens on Twitch.

My current Code is this:

```
TwitchAPIexample.RootObject json = TwitchAPIexample.BuildConnect();

    if (TwitchAPIexample.TwitchLive(json))
    {
        var channel = client.GetChannel("announcements"); //Where I need to get channel
        //Where I need to send message to channel
    }
```

The file where I am pulling the code from:

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MyFirstBot.Plugins
{
    public class TwitchAPIexample
    {

        private const string url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/channel";

        public bool isTwitchLive = true;

        public static RootObject BuildConnect()
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            request.Method = "Get";
            request.Timeout = 12000;
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Headers.Add("authorization", "Token");

            using (System.IO.Stream s = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s))
                {
                    var jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    RootObject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonResponse);
                    return r;
                }
            }
        }


        public class Preview
        {
            public string small { get; set; }
            public string medium { get; set; }
            public string large { get; set; }
            public string template { get; set; }
        }

        public class Channel
        {
            public bool mature { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
            public string broadcaster_language { get; set; }
            public string display_name { get; set; }
            public string game { get; set; }
            public string language { get; set; }
            public int _id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string created_at { get; set; }
            public string updated_at { get; set; }
            public bool partner { get; set; }
            public string logo { get; set; }
            public string video_banner { get; set; }
            public string profile_banner { get; set; }
            public object profile_banner_background_color { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
            public int views { get; set; }
            public int followers { get; set; }
        }

        public class Stream
        {
            public long _id { get; set; }
            public string game { get; set; }
            public int viewers { get; set; }
            public int video_height { get; set; }
            public int average_fps { get; set; }
            public int delay { get; set; }
            public string created_at { get; set; }
            public bool is_playlist { get; set; }
            public Preview preview { get; set; }
            public Channel channel { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public Stream stream { get; set; }
        }

        public static bool TwitchLive(RootObject stream)
        {
            TwitchAPIexample twitch = new TwitchAPIexample();
            string test = stream.stream.ToString();
            if(test == null)
            {
                twitch.isTwitchLive = false;
                return false;
            }
            else if(test != null & twitch.isTwitchLive == false)
            {
                twitch.isTwitchLive = true;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @caesay, Dude, you keep thinking that I haven't researched the *** out of this and cant find it when its just being sent to the discord without any input. I said in my question that I didnt want it coded for me in the previous one. Just wanted some one to help explain it to me so I could learn. I did get stuck on something and now I am trying to get help on one specific line of code. Literally how to get the channel with out input from user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to search for the channel, the docuementation for the library is here: http://rtd.discord.foxbot.me/

There's no reason to contain all of the twitch response objects if we're only checking for a certain property (if the channel is alive or not). It's quite easy to traverse a JSON tree and look for a specific item.

I've completed the problem in the code below, and added comments for you to follow in the hopes it can help you learn. Paste the following code into `Program.cs` of a console application.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DiscordClient client = null;
    // initialize client etc here.

    string twitchStreamId = "";
    string twitchApiKey = "";
    string discordServerName = "";
    string discordChannelName = "";

    // find discord channel
    var server = client.FindServers(discordServerName).FirstOrDefault();
    var channel = server.FindChannels(discordChannelName, ChannelType.Text).FirstOrDefault();

    var lastTwitchStatus = CheckTwitchStatusIsOnline(twitchStreamId, twitchApiKey);

    // send a message on startup always
    SendDiscordChannelMessage(channel, lastTwitchStatus);

    while (true)
    {
        // check the status every 10 seconds after that and if the status has changed we send a message
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        var status = CheckTwitchStatusIsOnline(twitchStreamId, twitchApiKey);

        // if the status has changed since the last time we checked, send a message
        if (status != lastTwitchStatus)
            SendDiscordChannelMessage(channel, status);

        lastTwitchStatus = status;
    }
}

private static void SendDiscordChannelMessage(Channel channel, bool twitchIsOnline)
{
    channel.SendMessage(twitchIsOnline ? "Twitch channel is now live!!" : "Twitch channel is now offline :(");
}

private static bool CheckTwitchStatusIsOnline(string streamId, string twitchApiKey)
{
    // send a request to twitch and check whether the stream is live.
    var url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + streamId;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Timeout = 12000;
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Headers.Add("authorization", twitchApiKey);

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
        var jsonStream = jsonObject["stream"];

        // twitch channel is online if stream is not null.
        var twitchIsOnline = jsonStream.Type != JTokenType.Null;
        return twitchIsOnline;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not going to copy the code unless my stuff doesn't work, because I dont want to just copy a whole section. Im try to understand how the discord section works. And Its not that I am bad at researching, its that I dont know C# well enough to decode the githubs and understand. Thats Why I come here asking for some guidance. Sorry if I came of as lazy. But Behind the scenes I am trying to learn but I this program is what I am using to learn.

Thank you for the section that finds the server and the channel. I did incorporate that

Comment: I know this happened over a year ago, and this actually isn't anything to do what I want - but you went the extra mile for Zack and he didn't upvote you... So I will :P